# Dialog close button lacks styles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the JQuery UI dialog:

```
$("#filter").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable:false
});
```

The close button in their example has:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="close">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">close</span></button>
```

Mine has:

```
<button class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close"></button>
```

Why does my button not have those styles. I have included the theme and I see the theme for everything else...

Thanks

Comment: Is that button created by the dialog?  Or are you manually putting that button in there?

Comment: It is created by the dialog

Comment: Do you have any other scripts that might modify the dialog's DOM? The elements are as expected in [this minimal example](http://jsfiddle.net/yxw7X/).

Comment: Nope, nothing special... this really should work...

Comment: I can confirm that the buttons are generated badly when bootstrap.js (2.3.2) is loaded. If bootstrap.js is not loaded the buttons are generated fine (using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery-UI 1.10.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be caused by the Use of the jQuery UI js with the Twitter Bootsrap js

Answer (score 0):

The styles will only apply if `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` is wrapped inside an element with class `.ui-dialog`.

I would suggest you to just look at the styles that you like and create a new style declaration for the button.